# How to insert values into database SQL

Tags: sql

Table `studentdata`:

| ID | Name | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Paul | 1st |

Table `HolidayList`:

| Date | Holiday_Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11-12-2022 | Sunday | H |

Output:

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | Outtime | INAM | OUTPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Paul | 1st | 09-12-2022 | Holiday | Holiday | H | H |

Code:

```
SELECT
    studentdata.ID, studentdata.Name, studentdata.Class,
    HolidayList.Date AS Date, HolidayList.Holiday_Name AS Intime,
    Holiday_Name AS Outtime, HolidayList.Status AS INAM,
    HolidayList.Status AS OUTPM 
FROM
    studentdata 
CROSS JOIN 
    HolidayList
```

From this code, I'm getting the output shown, but how can I insert these values into `table1` in my database? Thank you...

Comment: Use this form: `insert into table1 (field1,field2,field3) select field1,field2,field3 from table`

Comment: By using `INSERT INTO`. Read your lesson/tutorial/book to learn how to use it. If you don't have one of those things, find one and use it. This is a very basic question, which any decent book or tutorial will cover for you..